# showing old image even after new image is being uploaded

Tags: php, image, apache, caching, file-upload

I'm uploading file using php and displaying it as soon as uploading competed. Sometimes it shows old image, doesn't showing newly uploaded. but hitting refresh will display new image. How can I get rid of this? I'm using apache web server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is due to browser's cache. Try to add a random number in filename path, e.g.

```
<img src="image.jpg?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" />
```

of course, the `rand` is generated by random function ( PHP / Javascript ) each time.

Comment: take into account that putting this ALWAYS will basically disable caching for that image, so probably you only want this when showing the image just after the upload

Answer (score 4):

you're getting cached image, to append random value to you image source, like:

```
your_image.png?t=<?php echo time(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

This way you can keep it cached as long as it is not modified, and serve the fresh image as soon as it is modified.

```
<img src="image.jpg?t=<?php echo filemtime('image.jpg'); ?>" />
```

Note: This will not disable cache completely But serve fresh image if available.

Comment: Underated answer! I don't want to prevent caching completely. +1